# Fatten lists (but not other iterables) inside a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data structure:

```
a = ['test', 32, ('tuple', 'example'), ['a', 'b', 2], ['c', 'd', 3]]
```

I want:

```
b = ['test', 32, ('tuple', 'example'), 'a', 'b', 2, 'c', 'd', 3]
```

I tried:

```
c = [a[0], a[1], a[2], [l for l in a[3]], [j for j in a[4]]]
```

That results in c matching a. I also tried:

```
c = [a[0], a[1], a[2], ''.join(str(l) for l in a[3]), ''.join(str(j) for j in a[4])]
> c
['test', 32, ('tuple', 'example'), 'ab2', 'cd3']
```

That results in the join making everything a string.  Where's my join that turns my list into 3 items?  It seems like the only way to do this is to specify each index of the sublists, which is silly IMO.

```
c = [a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3][0], a[3][1], a[3][2], a[4][0], a[4][1], a[4][2]]
> c
['test', 32, ('tuple', 'example'), 'a', 'b', 2, 'c', 'd', 3]
```

How to best derive my desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

comprehension is your friend:

```
[i for e in a for i in (e if isinstance(e, list) else [e])]
```

demo:

```
>>> a = ['test', 32, ('tuple', 'example'), ['a', 'b', 2], ['c', 'd', 3]]
>>> [i for e in a for i in (e if isinstance(e, list) else [e])]
['test', 32, ('tuple', 'example'), 'a', 'b', 2, 'c', 'd', 3]
```

#### UPDATE

we should read 2 fors in this comprehension individually:

```
[i 
 for e in a # first
 for i in (e if isinstance(e, list) else [e])] # second
```

this comprehension works with 2 layers of for. the first one iterates through your original list `a`, and extract each element out and call them `e`.

as what you need is to flatten all `list`s, we will need another layer to do the flattening, which comes to be the second for. since the if-else part handles 2 scenario: one for the list case and one for the others. when it's a list, you want to iterate through the content of it, while for the rest, you want to keep it like this, so the simpliest way to do it is just to wrap the element inside of a `list` to create a singleton. then we will just need to return whatever inside of this processed list one by one, that is `i` in this case.

Comment: Can you explain how this works a little better please?  I understand that (e if isinstance(e,list) else [e]) returns the element if it's a list or a created list with the element inside if it's not a list.  But how does the other list comprehension work?  [i for i in a] I understand.  I don't understand referencing e twice (once in the list comprehension and once in the parens.

Comment: That's great!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use this to sort through each type in a:

```
a = ['a',('tuple','example'),['b','c','d'],5]
newa = []
for x in a:
    if type(x) is list:
        for y in x:
            newa.append(y)
    else:
        newa.append(x)

print(newa)
```

Not very efficient, but hey, it works.

**Edit**:
You could also use this:

```
a = ['a',('tuple','example'),['b','c','d'],5]
newa = []
flattentypes = [list]
for x in a:
    if type(x) in flattentypes:
        for y in x:
            newa.append(y)
    else:
        newa.append(x)

print(newa)
```

Comment: The OP does not want to flatten tuples

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most readable approach is a simple `for` loop that extends lists items and appends non-list items to a new list:

```
a = ['test', 32, ('tuple', 'example'), ['a', 'b', 2], ['c', 'd', 3]]
ans = []
for item in a:
     ans.extend(item) if isinstance(item,list) else ans.append(item)
# ans: ['test', 32, ('tuple', 'example'), 'a', 'b', 2, 'c', 'd', 3]
```